# Subcolumn horizontal spacing problem with tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

I have tried to make as small code example as possible for this. However, it needs some amount of code I am afraid.

I start with the output:

[image: The output when I'm building my poster]

As you can see, I have between the "normal" columns succeeded in controlling the space between the columns with actual content to a fraction of 0.005, that is 0.5% of the page width.

In the subcolumn environment however, I get some much broader undesired horizontal gap between the subcolumns.

It should be mentioned that I use both `subcolspace = 0 mm` and `colspace = 0 mm` in my code, so as far as I understand - this should not happen!

Below is my entire code for an as small example as I managed to create:

```
\documentclass[a0paper, subcolspace = 0 mm, colspace = 0 mm, landscape, innermargin = 0 mm,  margin = 0 mm, blockshorizontalspace = 0 mm, blocksverticalspace = 0 mm, 25 pt]{tikzposter} % See Section 3

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\usetheme{Envelope}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{.50\textheight}
\makeatother

\settitle{ }

\begin{columns} 

\column{0.6975} 

\block[bodyoffsety=-2cm,bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,bodyinnersep = 12 mm,titleinnersep = 0em,roundedcorners=0]{}{\fontsize{130pt}{130pt}\selectfont This till be the title}

         \begin{subcolumns}
             \subcolumn{0.5}
             \block[titlewidthscale = 0, bodyoffsetx=-0cm,bodyoffsety=-0cm,bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,bodyinnersep = 12 mm,titleinnersep = 0em,roundedcorners=0]{}{\fontsize{130pt}{130pt}\selectfont Left subcolumn}

             \subcolumn{0.5}
             \block[titlewidthscale = 0, bodyoffsetx=-0cm,bodyoffsety=-2cm,bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,bodyinnersep = 12 mm,titleinnersep = 0em,roundedcorners=0]{}{\fontsize{130pt}{130pt}\selectfont Right subcolumn}
         \end{subcolumns}

\column{0.005}

\column{0.2975}
\block[bodyoffsety=-2cm,bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,bodyinnersep = 3 mm,titleinnersep = 0em,roundedcorners=0]{}{\center A Figure}
%%%\note{Notetext} % See Section 4.3

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

---

**Update**

I have come so far now, with a slightly cleaner code that I can see that it is related to `bodyinnersep = ** mm`.

With `bodyinnersep = 12 mm` the resulting output looks like:

[image: How it looks with bodyinnersep at 12 mm]

And with `bodyinnersep = 0 mm` the resulting output looks like:

[image: How it looks with bodyinnersep at 0 mm]

Thus, one can conclude that:

- For high or nonzero values of `bodyinnersep`:

  1. the blocks can be able to contain their own contents
  2. the horizontal spacing between the blocks will not reflect the intentions of the LaTeX code
- For zero or low values of `bodyinnersep`:

  1. the blocks will no longer be able to contain their own contents
  2. but the horizontal spacing between the blocks will now, on the other hand reflect the intentions of the LaTeX code.

So the quesion is how one can make sure that block contents can be inside the block without the block positions being altered.

In a more complicated case, increasing the value of `bodyinnersep` made also the 0.5% gap between the subcolumns and the "figure" be covered/blocked by the rightmost subcolumn. Since "minimal working examples" are preferred here, I wait with showing that one.

Comment: I've come so far I understand it is related to `bodyinnersep`. If I set it to zero, the spacing will function as one logically could expect, but then there will be problems with the placement of the text.