# Distance between subcolumns with Tikzposter

Tags: columns, tikzposter

I am trying to make a poster with columns and subcolumns using Tikzposter. But the distance between the two subcolumns is larger than the one between the two main columns. How can I reduce the distance between the two subcolumns?

Here's my code and its output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}

\column{0.60}
    \block{Block 1}{\lipsum[1]} 

    \begin{subcolumns}
        \subcolumn{0.50}
            \block{Block 2}{\lipsum[2]}
        \subcolumn{0.50}
            \block{Block 3}{\lipsum[3]}
    \end{subcolumns}    

\column{0.40} 
    \block{Block 4}{\lipsum[4]}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've actually find out that there is a "subcolspace" parameter which can be declared with \documentclass and can be negative.

Taking as first line

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape, subcolspace=-.5cm]
```

seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in `tikzposter`. There is [another unanswered question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443172/subcolumn-horizontal-spacing-problem-with-tikzposter) on the same issue.

As a workaround, don't use `subcolumns` and add another `columns`-environment instead. You can add `colspace=<x>mm` as an argument of the documentclass, to adjust the spacing between the blocks.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{columns}
\column{0.6}
    \block{Block 1}{\lipsum[1]} 

\column{0.40} 
    \block{Block 4}{\lipsum[4]}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
  \block{Block 2}{\lipsum[2]}
\column{0.3}
 \block{Block 3}{\lipsum[3]}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, actually there is a "subcolspace" parameter as well!